# How pass variable to vue-router v-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue component to render nav list, and pass nav list, each item includes title and link:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list"><a v-link="{{ path: item.link }}"></a></li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['list']
  }
</script>
```

I try pass variable `item.link` to v-link path, but failed.

get this warn:

```
[Vue warn]: v-link="{{ path: item.link }}": attribute interpolation is not allowed in Vue.js directives and special attributes.
```

what should i do if pass variable to v-link path?

thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the statement in v-link doesn't need “Mustache” syntax.

```html
<li v-for="item in list"><a v-link="{ path: item.link }"></a></li>
```

you can see http://router.vuejs.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 23):

I used the following with [vue-router 2.x](https://router.vuejs.org/en/):

```
<router-link :to="{path: '/applications/' + currentApplicationId}" class="nav-link">Overview</router-link>
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html).

Answer (score 21):

Shorter way would be:

```js
<router-link :to="`/applications/${currentApplicationId}`">Overview</router-link>
```

Comment: I would argue that this is the appropriate answer for readability, router link, and ease of use